# Não colorir data atual com FullCalendar

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

Tenho uma agenda em fullcalendar, e estou tentando não colorir o dia de hoje..

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

note que ele está em amarelo claro (seg 1/4)

Alguma dica?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode usar o código **CSS** abaixo para sobrescrever essa configuração:

```
.fc-today {
    background: #FFF !important;
    border: none !important;
    border-top: 1px solid #ddd !important;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Lembrando que o código deve ficar abaixo da chamada do arquivo **CSS** do **FullCalendar**.

Comment: Tinha achado no CSS  .fc td.fc-today { background-color: #ffffff !important;} mas assim dá certo tb! Obrigado